# Sync Data between Microsoft CRM online and Oracle Database On prime

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I want to Push data from On Prime Oracle Database to Microsoft CRM Online, Better is without using any 3rd party Connector, I have Oracle Data Integerator,SSIS and Power automate. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you facing issue with Power Automate and Oracle connector ?

Comment: I am looking for possible ways to acheive this